# How to Create PostgreSQL Leading Zero Sequence (zerofill)

Tags: postgresql, zerofill

How can I create a leading zero sequence in PostgreSQL?

For MySQL I know it is `BIGINT(10) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT` but in PostgreSQL I can't find an equivalent (only `bigserial`).

Moreover how can I limit the number of zeroes as `BIGINT(10)` means 10 symbols, does the type `bigserial` have such a limit?

Comment: `BIGINT(10)` does ***not*** limit the values to only 10 digits in MySQL. You can store any number you like in a column defined like that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create a regular sequence, then use to_char() to pad it with leading zeroes. Your data type will be char(), though, Postgres does not support zerofill for integral types.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of something like this, but I was wondering if there is another way. So it comes something like this: 
`CREATE SEQUENCE seq_test INCREMENT 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 START 1 CACHE 1;` and then for the key: `id character(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT to_char(nextval('seq_test'), '0000000000') PRIMARY KEY`. Still wondering why `character(10)` doesn't work while the symbols are 10 :)

Comment: to_char() adds an extra space before the digits that is used for negative sign when your integer is negative. I.e. if you use 10 '0's in the pattern you'll get an 11-character string.

Comment: You can remove the space from to_char() by using the `FM` prefix: `to_char(1, 'FM0000')`

Answer (score 11):

A good alternative to `to_char()` in a "fill leading zeros" task is `lpad()`:

```
create table TableName(columnName serial primary key);

select lpad(columnName::text, 3, '0'), * from TableName;
```

Caution: `lpad()` does not generate an error on overflow, see for example:

```
select lpad(4444::text, 3, '0'), to_char(4444, '000')
```

Comment: Translating to a generic answer: `lpad()` is a good alternative to `to_char()` in a "fill leading zeros" task. CAUTION: `lpad` not generates an error on overflow, see `SELECT lpad(4444::text, 3, '0'), to_char(4444, '000')`.